# Getting ASCII code with Gforth

Tags: char, forth, gforth

When entering `'a'` in Gforth, the ASCII number of the character (the same number which would be put onto the stack by using the [`key`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Single_002dkey-input.html#Single_002dkey-input) word and pressing <kbd>a</kbd>) is put onto the stack.

This does not work for example with `' '` (space). Instead:

```
' '  ok
.s <1> 34384939008  ok
```

The number “should” be 32. What explains this behavior? And what can be done about it – aside from manually putting the ASCII number corresponding to  `' '` (space) on the stack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This `'a'` syntax is quite new to Forth.  It's added as an extension on top of the traditional syntax which parses everything into whitespace-delimited tokens.  So `'a'` is one atomic token, which is then parsed as a character literal.

Now, `' '` isn't an atomic token, since it contains a space character.  Rather, it's parsed as two `'` tokens.  It's actually perfectly valid Forth code, because [`'` is a Forth word (called "tick")](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Execution-token.html).  In your example, the first tick operates on the second.  The result, `34384939008`, is the xt for `'`.

What to do instead?  The traditional words for getting the ASCII code of a character is `CHAR` or `[CHAR]`.  The first works in interpreted mode, and the second in compiled mode.  **BUT** they don't work for the particular case of the space character, because again, all whitespace is parsed away.

However, there is another word which pushes the ASCII code space character: `BL`.

Comment: lol, tick is not even an esoteric word... embarrassing ;-) I just started with FORTH and missed that.

Comment: just one question: what may be the reason that there are two different versions `char` and `[char]` in runtime and compile mode?

Comment: In interpreted code, only `CHAR` is meaningful.

But both `CHAR` and `[CHAR]` can be useful in compiled code.  `[CHAR]` works at compile time, so it parses the next word in the program.  `CHAR` works at run time, so it doesn't operate on the program text, but ta the input stream at a later time.  This can be handy in e.g. immediate words.